# Submitting a form to a page where the page changes based on the form elements?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

When submitting a form, the submission page is based on an element in the form. For example:

```html
<form method="post" action="/submit/[user_form_field]">
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="hidden" name="userdata" value="userdatavalue">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In submitting "test" in the user field, the form should POST the userdata field to `/submit/test`

A separate, but similar option, is this could also be handled without posting anything at all. Given almost the same form:

```html
<form method="get" action="/submit/[user_form_field]">
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In this case, the person entering "test" as a user would just be redirected to "`/submit/test`" instead of "`/submit?user=test`"

Basically, for the second part, is there a way to remove the "`?user=`" part when submitting a "GET" form?

Comment: Explain more details on your question.

Comment: Why don't you call the function with PHP?
Yo get the user=test and later in the submit function, call the function test() or caramel() or whatever you want.

Comment: What more details can I share specifically? If I'm not being clear please let me know what more I can add.

Comment: @antoiba86 I'm not sure what you're saying. I'm 99% sure this has to be done with javascript. I'm trying to avoid the ?user= part of the URL completely.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working myself:

```
<script>
 function change_action(formchange)
    {
        document.formchange.action = "/submit/" + document.getElementById("user").value;
    }
</script>
```

```
<form method="post" name="formchange" id="formchange" action="/submit">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" onchange="change_action(this.form)"> ';
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It still posts too so it does everything I needed.